# DJANGO - python manage.py migrate - ERROR: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column in 'field list'")

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have changed the default database in Django project to database, which I have created in MySQL Workbench, which contains tables and relationships between them.

`settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'data_storage',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

I am following the instructions in:
https://rafed.github.io/devra/posts/database/how-to-connect-django-to-existing-database/

Running `python manage.py inspectdb > my_app/models.py` generated models successfully.

After I run cmdlet `python manage.py migrate`, I get error: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'auth_permission.content_type_id' in 'field list'")`

FULL PROMPT:

```
(.venv) PS C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp> python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: DjangoWebPage, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 75, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 158, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 325, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 549, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 779, in _read_query_result     
    result.read()
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1157, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 729, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'auth_permission.content_type_id' in 'field list'")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute    
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv  
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute        
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 268, in handle
    emit_post_migrate_signal(
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\sql.py", line 42, in emit_post_migrate_signal
    models.signals.post_migrate.send(
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 180, in send
    return [
           ^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 181, in <listcomp>      
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\__init__.py", line 72, in create_permissions
    all_perms = set(Permission.objects.using(using).filter(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 280, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 140, in __iter__
    return compiler.results_iter(tuple_expected=True, chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1124, in results_iter
    results = self.execute_sql(MULTI, chunked_fetch=chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1169, in execute_sql 
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 75, in execute       
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 158, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 325, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 549, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 779, in _read_query_result     
    result.read()
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1157, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 729, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "C:\Users\Prakse\Desktop\DjangoApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'auth_permission.content_type_id' in 'field list'")
```

`auth_permision` table in `models.py`:

```
class AuthPermission(models.Model):
    permission_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    fk_content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContent', models.DO_NOTHING)
    codename = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_permission'
        unique_together = (('permission_id', 'fk_content_type'),)
```

Integrate MySQL Workbench database in Django project.